# Not understanding how the compiler searches for includes

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++, header-files

So, I'm trying to include C++ header files that are in an adjacent file and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get the compiler to find them. All I can do is move all of my files into the same folder and then all of the sudden it finds them. Well, I take that back, I can specify the entire file path and it works, but I see people all the time using just

```
<sub1/filename.h>
```

when their source is in subdir/sub2/source.cpp and the header is in subdir/sub2/source.h. How do I make this magic happen?

Comment: What compiler are you using? And when you say "cpp header files", do you mean C++, or do the file names actually have a `.cpp` extension? `cpp` is a common extension for source files, but it's not the name of the language.

Comment: g++ I believe. Whatever comes with xcode. And I mean C++, not actual cpp extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two points:

1) For a *system* header file, it's appropriate to use `#include <sysheader.h>` syntax.
But for your *own* headers, you should instead us `#include "myheader.h"`.

2) Use the compile switch "-I" to make the compiler search in the specified folder(s) for your own headers.

Comment: Any idea how to do that with cmake?

Comment: Use [include_directories](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include_directories.html) for cmake.